# How to handle dojo listbox in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dojo, selenium-webdriver

I having a dojo dropdown, on the webpage that I am automating. I have to click on the down arrow key displayed and a dropdown appears. The HTML for the same isas below. I tried handling it using javascript executor, and my code snippet is as below-. I am sure it is wrong as I havent got much info on how to handle this kind of dropdown- I am trying to select the 2 Adults option. Website is - http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/ua/homepage. Dropdown is for number of passengers

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ns_7_CO19VHUC6N5PC0ACV6A7BG2I12_fmAdults']/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
select.click();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String jscript = "dojo.addOnLoad(function() { dijit.byId('ns_7_CO19VHUC6N5PC0ACV6A7BG2I12_fmAdults_menu').set('id','dijit_MenuItem_7_text') })";           
js.executeScript(jscript);
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="ns_7_CO19VHUC6N5PC0ACV6A7BG2I12_fmAdults_dropdown" class="dijitPopup dijitMenuPopup" style="visibility: visible; top: 307px; left: 953.5px; right: auto; z-index: 1000; height: auto; overflow: visible;" role="region" aria-label="ns_7_CO19VHUC6N5PC0ACV6A7BG2I12_fmAdults_menu" dijitpopupparent="ns_7_CO19VHUC6N5PC0ACV6A7BG2I12_fmAdults">
<table id="ns_7_CO19VHUC6N5PC0ACV6A7BG2I12_fmAdults_menu" class="dijit dijitReset dijitMenuTable dijitSelectMenu dijitValidationTextBoxMenu dijitMenuActive dijitMenu dijitMenuSelected dijitSelected dijitMenuHover dijitMenuSelectedHover dijitSelectedHover dijitHover dijitMenuFocused dijitMenuSelectedFocused dijitSelectedFocused dijitMenuHoverFocused dijitMenuSelectedHoverFocused dijitSelectedHoverFocused dijitHoverFocused dijitFocused" cellspacing="0" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" widgetid="ns_7_CO19VHUC6N5PC0ACV6A7BG2I12_fmAdults_menu" style="top: 0px; visibility: visible; width: 184px;" aria-labelledby="ns_7_CO19VHUC6N5PC0ACV6A7BG2I12_fmAdults">
<tbody class="dijitReset" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
<tr id="dijit_MenuItem_2" class="dijitReset dijitSelectSelectedOption dijitValidationTextBoxSelectedOption dijitMenuItemSelected dijitMenuItem dijitMenuItemHover dijitHover dijitMenuItemFocused dijitMenuItemHoverFocused dijitHoverFocused dijitFocused" tabindex="0" role="option" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-label="2 Adults &nbsp; " aria-disabled="false" widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_2" aria-selected="true">
<td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemIconCell" role="presentation">
<td id="dijit_MenuItem_2_text" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode" colspan="2">2  Adults  </td>
<td id="dijit_MenuItem_2_accel" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemAccelKey" data-dojo-attach-point="accelKeyNode" style="display: none"/>
<td class="dijitReset dijitMenuArrowCell" role="presentation">
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Java Script Executor!, For each element in the drop down table it is under 'dijitMenuItemLabel' class, so get all these element in one List and according to the requirement click on particular element.
Here's the code!

```
  WebElement adultDrpDwnButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ns_7_CO19VHUC6N5PC0ACV6A7BG2I12_fmAdults']/tbody/tr/td[2]"));
 adultDrpDwnButton.click(); //click on the Adult Drop Down Button
 WebDriverWait waitForDrpDown = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
 waitForDrpDown.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ns_7_CO19VHUC6N5PC0ACV6A7BG2I12_fmAdults_menu']/tbody")));
 //after clicking the button it will wait for the drop down to be visible,if it is not visible in 5 Seconds, then it will throw an error
 List<WebElement> drpListItems = driver.findElements(By.className("dijitMenuItemLabel"));
 //now get all the element which is under 'dijitMenuItemLabel', there will be 6 elements in the List varibale drpListItems,
 //you can check that by using drpListItems.size()
for(WebElement temp : drpListItems){  //now use special for loop and go through the each element and click on the particular element based on the reqiuirement
if(temp.getText().trim().equals("5 Adults")){
    temp.click();
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. One thing which I am not able to understand is that why have you used class name as dijitMenuItemLabel? I see it as dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel.

Comment: In the visibility condition line of code , the xpath of the adult menu is given , but nt the xpath of the dropdown. As you have mentioned that this will wait for the dropdown, so I thought that xpath of the dropdown would be used?

Comment: Please ignore the above comment.

Comment: Applied the same code as above - still not working. Gives the error- Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.dijitMenuItemLabel']' is not a valid selector.
  (Session info: chrome=37.0.2062.103)